# C# WPF DataGrid setting multiple selected items programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF window `ViewAssignedStudentsWindow` with the following constructor:

```
public ViewAssignedStudentsWindow(IEnumerable<StudentDTO> allStudents, MandatoryLessonDTO lesson)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    studentsGrid.ItemsSource = allStudents;
    studentsGrid.SelectedItems.Add(allStudents.Where(x => lesson.StudentIds.Contains(x.Id)));
}
```

The `StudentDTO` has properties `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Id` and some others, which should not be important for this problem. `StudentIds` property in the `MandatoryLessonDTO` class is an `IEnumerable<Guid>` which holds some of the students' Ids. The xaml of `ViewAssignedStudentWindow`:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"  IsReadOnly="true" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ColumnWidth="*" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" AutoGenerateColumns="false" x:Name="studentsGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that the grid gets filled with the students' data, however the `SelectedItems` doesn't seem to work - none of the items are selected. If I try to debug the code, the LINQ seems to yield correct results, however the `SelectedItems` stays empty. I am completely lost at this point why this isn't working, it seems like such a simple task. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `DataBinding` to an Items property here.

your students class:

```
public class Students : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private bool _selected;
    public bool Selected {
        get { return _selected; }
        set {
            if (value == _selected) return;
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Add a `RowStyle` to your DG:

```
<DataGrid ... >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Selecting Rows from CodeBehind:

```
public ViewAssignedStudentsWindow(IEnumerable<StudentDTO> allStudents, MandatoryLessonDTO lesson)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    studentsGrid.ItemsSource = allStudents;
    allStudents.ForEach(x => x.Selected = lesson.StudentIds.Contains(x.Id)));
}
```